# Excel VBA code to open a file

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro button to open my daily files from a excel production sheet where I have all the my macro button for specific files.

The format for all my files are conventionally the same:

1. Businese Unit Name: YMCA
2. Year:2012
3. Month: April
4. Week: Week 2
5. Day: 12
6. File Name: YMC Template 041212.xlsm

I am having issue with the last excel file name extension.
how do I add the MyDaily Template and MyDateProd along with the .xlsm.
I have this -J:.....\& myDailyTemplate & myDateProd.xlsm") see below for entire file path names.

```
Sub Open_DailyProd()

    Dim myFolderYear As String
    Dim myFolderMonth As String
    Dim myFolderWeek As String
    Dim myFolderDaily As String
    Dim myDateProd As String
    Dim myBusinessUnit As String
    Dim myDailyTemplate As String

    myBusinessUnit = Sheet1.Cells(32, 2)
    myFolderYear = Sheet1.Cells(11, 2)
    myFolderMonth = Sheet1.Cells(12, 2)
    myFolderWeek = Sheet1.Cells(13, 2)
    myFolderDaily = Sheet1.Cells(14, 2)
    myDateProd = Sheet1.Cells(15, 2)
    myDailyTemplate = Sheet1.Cells(6, 5)

    Application.Workbooks.Open ("J:\IAS\3CMC05HA01\IAC Clients\myBusinessUnit\myFolderYear\myFolderMonth\myFolderWeek\myFolderDaily\& myDailyTemplate & myDateProd.xlsm")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Excel is looking for a file called:
`"J:\IAS\3CMC05HA01\IAC Clients\myBusinessUnit\myFolderYear\myFolderMonth\myFolderWeek\myFolderDaily\& myDailyTemplate & myDateProd.xlsm"`

since that is what is included in the quotes, but from your code, you appear to have a number of variables that are part of this string, you need to take them out of the quotes and concatenate them together.  Try something like this:

```
"J:\IAS\3CMC05HA01\IAC Clients\" & myBusinessUnit & "\" & myFolderYear _
& "\" & myFolderMonth & "\" & myFolderWeek & "\" & myFolderDaily & _
"\" & myDailyTemplate & myDateProd & ".xlsm"
```

I added the continuation _ to make it more readable onthe screen here, but it is not necessary, you can put everything on one line together if you prefer.

Unless you need all of the `myBusinessUnit`, `myFolderYear`, etc variables elsewhere, I would think about doing it in some sort of array and then doing a `Join` function to concatenate everything.  I, personally, find this easier to maintain going forward and easier to see the hierarchy in the folder structure rather than looking at a very long string and trying to find what part of the path is wrong.

```
Sub Open_DailyProd()

    Dim pathParts(1 To 10) As String
    Dim path As String

    pathParts(1) = "J:"
    pathParts(2) = "IAS"
    pathParts(3) = "3CMC05HA01"
    pathParts(4) = "IAC Clients"
    pathParts(5) = Sheet1.Cells(32, 2)
    pathParts(6) = Sheet1.Cells(11, 2)
    pathParts(7) = Sheet1.Cells(12, 2)
    pathParts(8) = Sheet1.Cells(13, 2)
    pathParts(9) = Sheet1.Cells(14, 2)
    pathParts(10) = Sheet1.Cells(6, 5) & Sheet1.Cells(15, 2) & ".xlsm"

    path = Join(pathParts, "\")

    Application.Workbooks.Open (path)

End Sub
```

Comment: I am having issuw with the     path = Join(pathPart, "\").

Comment: @cemg i should have prefaced it with "untested" as I did not try it before i wrote it.  The basic idea is sound though.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @cemg I had a typo in my code, but fixed it, and I tested this time.  It should be working for you.  If it doesn't, then you need to consider that either the file you are asking for does not exist at that location or the path has a typo

Comment: Personally, I would just stick with the `&` concatenation. You're right that the variables are not needed, but making an array is also just another unneeded step. i.e. `"J:\IAS\3CMC05HA01\IAC Clients\" & Sheet1.Cells(32, 2)...`

Comment: @Gaffi the alternative is personal preference.  I've done both in the past and with a variable path this long, i just have found it easier to troubleshoot and change when you break it up into parts and join them together, so i thought i would mention it

Comment: To each his own. FWIW, I still give this answer a +1. :-)

Comment: Is there a way to make this code DYNAMIC by having a macro to the following: 1. Create a Folder according to a New Month, New Week and New Day, 2. Move the Files from prior Folders to newly created Folders, 3. change the template name by only the new date.

Comment: @cemg sure it's possible, but too complex to answer within the scope of your original question.  I think you would be best served to create a new question detailing these requirements and show what you have tried.